# Google Calendar API in standalone app

Tags: php, symfony, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I'm currently working in a CRM integration with Google Calendar API, to syncronize events between my CRM program and G Calendar. Currently I can create, edit, view and delete events from my API in PHP. This integration is based in Symfony2 FW and the Djami's Google Calendar Bundle (https://github.com/Djamy/GoogleCalendarBundle) Everything works well, but there are some doubts I have:

This CRM is an standalone and distributable program, we should integrate the users' calendars without any service account, and by the moment, I can only work with calendars on Google accounts that have a developers' service account linked (with the P12 credential file). This is too difficult for the users. User should grant access to their calendars by giving username and password, without any action in Google Developers. Is there any way to reach this?

Another point we can't reach, is that when I delete an event from the calendar, and list them from the API, events still appear. Its like the event is not created in the user calendar, It looks more like the event is created in the google service account calendar (if it exists) and then shared to the "destination" calendar, and when I delete the event in Google Calendar Im just removing a link; I don't think I'm explaining properly with that but I can't find a better way to do it. I can only delete the event from the API.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Comment: Are you trying to give users access to a central Google Calendar or are you trying to access their individual calendars?   @JulianSchmuckli what code do you want to see exactly?

Comment: @DaImTo She wrote, that she can't delete the event.

Comment: @JulianSchmuckli sounds like she knows what its doing and is just confused at how service accounts work.   But i guess code would help with that one issue.

Comment: Many thanks to all the answers. I had to be more accurate, sorry. I'm working with Symfony2 and the Djamy's Google Calendar Bundle (https://github.com/Djamy/GoogleCalendarBundle). I've just modified the question explaining furtherly.

Comment: @DalmTo, the final objective is to handle one calendar per user